# Is it poor practice to call methods through multiple objects?

Tags: java

I have code that looks like this:

```
tr.t.findIndexSmoothed(arg0.getX(), arg0.getY());
```

"tr" and "t" are objects. Is it bad practice to reach all the way down the object hierarchy to call methods? The only reason I can think of is that is breaks encapsulation, and if that's the case, can anybody tell me why that poses a problem? Also, does this code structure inhibit performance in any way?

Comment: If the `t` member inside the `tr` object is reachable (`public`) then you are not breaking encapsulation: the purpose of making a member (field or method) public is to allow direct access to it.

Comment: Yes it is correct. Though if you abuse it, it can hinder readability and debugging (you get a `NullPointerException`, which is null, `tr`, `tr.t`or `arg0`?)

Comment: The answers here, as well as the answers on the question this is considered a duplicate of, overlook one key point:  **if `tr.t`'s signature is changed from whatever `class` is currently used, to a newly defined `interface`, then the "over-coupling" is broken.** Clients would know what they can do. `tr` can make any needed changes in future. It is the public exposure of a property as a class rather than a more limited interface, that is the root of the problem. (Typically: make `t` private, perhaps as `_t`, then add a getter that exposes `t`, but using an `interface` type.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) suggests that you shouldn't call methods on objects two layers down like that.

The idea is that, in your case, you should have a method findIndexSmoothed on tr which in turn calls findIndexSmoothed on t.

What this does is makes your code adaptable. It means that the nature of tr.findIndexSmoothed can change without necessarily changing the nature of t.findIndexSmoothed, which may be called by other code you don't intend to change.

However, it is commonly noted that it's pretty rare you really need that adaptability, and you'll have put yourself in a position where maintenance of t.findIndexSmoothed now requires maintenance of tr.findIndexSmoothed so, in some cases, you will increase your workload.

So, the answer to your question, as so many style questions in programming, is: Use your common sense. Keep the Law of Demeter in mind, but never make it an inflexible truth.

Comment: Also you dont really have a choice when using apis and frameworks. It is just not worth it. So sometimes you will have chains of getX().getY().getZ()

Comment: The linked article about LOD seems to ignore a fundamental issue: *ownership*. If a piece of code owns an object (typically by holding the only reference to it anywhere in the universe) and the object provides a place for its owner to store something, that place would be owned by the owner of the object containing it, and that owner would be entitled to use it just as it would one of its own fields.

Comment: @supercat: If I'm understanding what you mean, that's exactly what LoD advises you not to do. Each object should have only one owner, which should pass it to child objects as method parameters or expose methods that allow parent objects to access the "grandchild" indirectly. Again, I'm not arguing for the LoD as a hard-and-fast rule here, I'm explaining why there's no mention of multiple ownership in an article about the Law of Demeter -- because the two things are orthogonal.

Comment: @pdr: My my understanding, the main purpose of the Law of Demeter is to ensure that any change to some aspect of an object's state should go through the object in question. If a `List<Car>` holds one element--a reference to the 592nd object created since startup, which is a `Car` whose `Color` is `"blue"`, then the state encapsulated by that `List<Car>` is the fact that item #0 holds a reference to Object #592. Code which owns the `List<Car>` might care about the fact that Object #592 has a `Color` of `"blue"`, but that information is not part of the state of the `List<Car>`.

Comment: @pdr: By my understanding of LoD, it would suggest that rather than asking the list for element 0, and asking the returned item its color, one should ask the list for the color of element 0.  The problem with that concept is that the list has no idea what a `Car` or a `Color` is. All it knows is that it holds a reference to Object #592. A class which encapsulated the *states* of many cars, and allowed client code to examine or manipulate them without exposing references, could be more safely shareable than `List<Car>`, but unless it *needs* to be shared would not be worth the trouble to code.

Comment: @supercat: Lists and arrays are definitely one of those examples where common sense has to kick in. Although a List<Car> is an object in and of itself, I'd argue that every element in that list is *really* one of "O's direct component objects". Take your point one step further and we'll talk about each character in a string being owned by the string, not by the object that owns the string. Or maybe ban bitwise operators for working on bits owned by an int. Strict adherance to LoD could definitely get that silly, but that doesn't nullify the guideline.

Comment: @pdr: Indeed.  Without knowing what the nature of `tr`, I can't really say whether `tr.t` should be considered part of `tr`, or whether it should be considered part of whatever holds the reference to `tr`.  While the *type* of `tr` may be somewhat relevant, I think a bigger issue is how it's used.  IMHO, the biggest problem which LOD tries to prevent could be covered by a rule that says that sharable objects which encapsulate their state in mutable objects should not expose those objects, and objects which encapsulate state in exposed mutable object should not be shared.

Comment: @supercat: I like that. I'm going to ponder it, and then probably steal it. :)

Comment: @pdr: Feel free. IMHO one of the great weaknesses of Java is that it only has one type of reference and does not distinguish whether any given reference encapsulates identity, mutable state, both, or neither. While it would be excessively expensive for a framework to support C++'s full litany of copy constructors etc. I think a good language should distinguish between fields which identify things whose state is part of that of the object holding the field, versus those which identify things whose state is owned by someone else. If the language used `.` for one and `->` for the other, then...

Comment: @pdr: ...I would interpret LOD as saying one should avoid using more than one `->` in an expression, or avoid using `->` on a reference (or portion the object identified thereby) which was itself received via `->`.  BTW, having such a distinction in the language would allow `clone`, `equals`, and `hashCode()` methods to be 99% automated.

Comment: @supercat: IMHO, there is another flaw to most double-level access that is equally important: overuse of exposing a *class* rather than an *interface*. If `tr.t` is an `interface` instead of a `class`, then `tr` has explicitly stated what is appropriate to do with `t`, removing the coupling. I prefer that approach, rather than creating a second kind of operator.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: What operations are appropriate with an instance of `t` will depend upon the purpose for which a reference is being held--something which the holder of the reference will know but the instance will not.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing wrong with it as long as it makes sense from the design point of view. Just ask yourself those questions:

1. Is it sensible for tr to contain and expose t?
2. Is findIndexSmoothed() the responsibility of t?

If you answer yes to both of the questions then it is a way to go. Only thing I would do differently is to make t private and access it via getter.

Also I think it actually makes sense with the single responsibility principle. What if t had 5 different methods? would you delegate all of those from tr? how would you name them? findIndexSmoothedInTr()?